# Sudden problems with WiFi on only two PCs although I didn't change anything

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I need your help

A view months back my mother’s PC had problems to connect to the internet (**Windows 7** 32 Bit, Asus P5Q Pro, Core 2 Duo E7500) so I bought her a “**ZyXEL NWD2205 USB Wireless Adapter**”, the same I’ve been using for almost two years without any problems. 
But even with the new adapter, the problems got worse. Her PC **loses connection all the time** and if there is connection it is **very slow**. 
I put the PC **right next to my wireless router**, it still downloaded with 300 Kb/s instead of 2.2 Mb/s.

A few days ago my own PC (**Windows 8** 64 Bit, Asus P9X79 Pro, I7 3930k) started to suddenly have the **exact same problems**, although I didn’t change anything about it and my two laptops and my phone don’t seem to have any problems at all.

The only thing these two PCs have in common is the “ZyXEL NWD2205” but my mother had another adapter before and when my PC was still ok (about a month ago) I switched adapters and it didn’t have any effect. So I don’t think the ZyXEL is broken.

---

What I already tried:

- I reset the router
- I changed the router’s channel
- I deactivated IPv6 because someone said it could help (it didn’t of course)
- I updated the driver for the ZyXEL

---

Could anyone help me please? I’m desperate …

Answer (score 0):

Note that the channels in the 2.4GHz band overlap each other quite a bit. So changing from channel 1 to channel 2 doesn't really change much. Try channels 1 and 13 (or whatever your highest channel is).

Also, make sure you have the latest firmware on your router. Note that the latest version may vary based on which hardware revision you have.

Consider running a tool like inSSIDer to see what channels nearby networks are using, so you can avoid them. Also use a spectrum analyzer such as a Wi-Spy if you have access to one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the firmware already, forgot to mention it. Also I tried a lot of different channels. My laptop doesn't have any problems from the same position, so it must be the two PCs and not the connection itself. I'm gonna download inSSIDer though, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run the 'tracert' command. Yeah, I know CLI stuff. It will show you if the bottleneck is between your computers and the router, which I suspect, or not. I would expect a time for the first hop to your router of less than 1ms. If it is much higher, you have a problem with the router. BTW I use Google DNS @ 8.8.8.8 just cause it is so brain dead simple to remember.

Comment: My mother's PC can't even connect to the network at the moment, my laptop doesn't have any problems at the same position (1.2 Mb/s down speed). So it can't be the router, right? But it can't be the wireless adapter either, because I already changed it from a Buffalo stick to the ZyXEL ...

Comment: Have you tried connecting using a wire? I really do suspect your router now as it may be intermittent. Try the tracert command and see what the times to the gateway are (this will be the first line).